# Is the full monetary amount of sub-contracting tax deductible?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, contractor, south-africa

At the moment I effectively work for myself, contracting full-time to a single company. I invoice this company `$x` every month.

In the near future, I would like to either hire or sub-contract other people, probably South Africans living in South Africa. Ideally I would then want to invoice the company a value of `$x` + `$y`. It is likely that `$x` will increase somewhat, so that will come with additional tax obviously. The entire value of `$y` will be paid to subcontractors/employees.

Is the entire amount of `$y` tax deductible? I would like to avoid finding myself in the position of paying increased taxes on money that "passes through me" so to speak.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote! I am new to this site, and would like engage more appropriately in the future. please be constructive.

Comment: What country are you living/paying taxes in?

Comment: i am a US citizen currently living abroad - so i pay taxes in the US, then file in South Africa

Comment: @ZachSmith Your wording on that last comment is a little ambiguous, so I want to point out what you may already know: If you are a US citizen earning money from another country, typically the *other* country has a right to tax that income first, and the US may or may not need additional taxes in some situations where your US tax bill would otherwise be higher than the 'local' tax. So, you may need to file in both countries, but as someone not living in the US and earning income from elsewhere, I would be quite shocked if you owed no taxes in that other country.

Comment: Thank @Grade'Eh'Bacon. I contract to a US company, so my income is all US-based (i.e. paid into a US bank account). I then wire money to South Africa.

Comment: Are you sure you can charge the company what you charge them now _plus_ the cost of the subcontractor?  Seems like that should come out of your existing revenue, otherwise it's essentially free labor.

Comment: @DStanley. The idea is that the company would want more work done, and would pay correspondingly more to me. Then I would subcontract and pay that contractor out of my revenue. but I am most likely going to set up a company of some kind

Comment: @ZachSmith OK fair enough.  _in general_ your subcontracting costs would be an expense that reduces your net income (is "deductible").

Comment: @ZachSmith The specifics of your situation may change the end result, but being paid into a US bank account does not *necessarily* mean the income was earned in the US. If you are physically present in country x, but doing work for a US company, it is possible that you are considered to have earned that money in country x, regardless of how your payment is routed. Be careful that you are not accidentally committing tax fraud.

Comment: (as an aside, if you are in a country with a lower tax rate than the US's, you may owe *less* tax by filing the income being sourced in that country. Look into the 'Foreign Earned Income Exclusion' rules on US tax filings for information).

Comment: Thanks - i do talk to an accountant. two accounts actually... one in each country

Comment: @ZachSmith Make sure your accountant(s) actually have experience dealing with foreign taxes. I have seen some real travesties completed by "professionals" who had no idea what they were doing and ignored the complexity, treating it like any other run-of-the-mill return. If you have this conversation with your accountants (preferably in some form where you can later prove if needed that your accountant had all necessary information, before they gave you their opinion), make sure you hold onto it as proof that you are trying hard to be compliant. And I could be wrong; I'm not second guessing.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - is it possible to be committing tax fraud if you pay too much tax, but it's incorrectly allocated? i.e. that the actual tax owed was less than what was paid

Comment: @ZachSmith Remember that there is no 'global tax authority'. If you pay $10k in tax to the US when it should have been $14k, but you pay $15k in tax to South Africa when it should have been $10, then yes, you will have 'overpaid' your global tax liability. However, the US will still want their extra $4k. There are ways to refile your returns in both countries under these circumstances, so that you get your refund back from South Africa, but that can be a long painful process, and ultimately the IRS wants its due, regardless of your tax overpayment to other countries.